# Grails/SpringSecurity core and customizing logout behaviour

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using grails 2.3.7 with SpringSecurityCore 2.0 .. I have two separate signon screens tailored for specific devices with the appropriate one triggered by accessing a specific controller. To do this I customized the loginController ..

```
/**
 * Show the login page.
 */

def auth() {

    def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        return
    }

    String whereFrom = session.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST.requestURI
    def rdt = whereFrom.contains('RDT')

    // Redirect for RDT as required  ..

    String view = rdt ? 'rauth' : 'auth'

    String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"

    session.rdt = rdt

    render view: view, model: [postUrl: postUrl,
                               rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]
}
```

which seems to work well .. On logout I want again to redirect to an appropriate screen .. I'm trying to use the session attribute I store on login along with a (admittedly old) link I found (http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Parameter-quot-logoutSuccessUrl-quot-in-spring-security-core-td2264147.html) to redirect back to an appropriate page ..

```
 /**
 * Index action. Redirects to the Spring security logout uri.
 */

def index() {

    if (!request.post && SpringSecurityUtils.getSecurityConfig().logout.postOnly) {
        response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED // 405
        return
    }

    // TODO put any pre-logout code here

    def rdt = session.rdt

    session.rdt = null

    // redirect uri: "/j_spring_security_logout?spring-security-redirect=$logoutUrl"

    if (rdt) {

        def link = g.createLink(controller: "RDT")
        def redirectUrl = "${SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl}?spring-security-redirect=${link}"

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect request, response, redirectUrl

    } else {
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect request, response, SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }

    response.flushBuffer()

}
```

Both options return me to the 'default' auth login screen and not my alternate  rauth one even with the addition of the extra parameter .. How can I route back to an appropriate screen ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I manually set the session variables to null, invalidate the session and a standard redirect ... works ..